# Respect Validation for two fields

Tags: php, validation, respect-validation

I need to validate form data with Respect. At least one of these fields must have a value: `$vfname` and `$vlname`.  After some trial and error, I found that I can concatenate and test with `notEmpty()`:

```
v::StringType()->notEmpty()->assert($vfname . $vlname)
```

But this seems really hacky. Is there a better way to validate so that at least one of these fields has a value?

Answer (score 2):

Validation supports `OR` operations with the `OneOf` rule. Besides, if you are validating form data, the `Key` rule will be handy:

```
v::oneOf(
    v::key('vfname', v::stringType()->notEmpty()),
    v::key('vlname', v::stringType()->notEmpty())
)
->assert(['vfname' => $vfname, 'vlname' => $vlname]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this then ?

```
v::boolType()->validate(!empty($vfname) || !empty($vlname));
```

Note : an advantage of using `empty()` is that it will not raise any `Undefined variable` notice, if it's a matter for you.